# jQuery Mobile navbar not scaling to correct size

Tags: jquery-mobile, resize, navbar

I'm trying jQuery's example on navbars but it's not working as intended.

When loading it on my notebook, navbar size is perfect.
When I try it on my phone, the buttons are cropped.

Here's the simple code:

```
<div data-role="footer">    
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

and here's what I get:

[image: Desktop]

[image: Mobile]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show us css you are using to customize your navbar? Unfortunately we cant tell you much without it.

Comment: it could be a conflict of jQuery Mobile CSS libraries like in your previous issue.

Comment: I'm using this theme without any editing: https://github.com/sgrebnov/jqmobile-metro-theme

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of the following issues:

1. The CSS for your jQuery.Mobile is outdated and/or is of a different version than the jquery.mobile.js file you are using.
2. You have added some custom css somewhere that is breaking this.
3. **This is my vote as most likely:** Somewhere else in the page, you have mismatched or unclosed tags, and the browser is compensating for it.  It is compensating for it correctly with the desktop browser (they tend to handle malformed code better), and not compensating correctly with the phone browser.  Thus unpredictable errors are the result.
4. Your external files are not linked in the correct order.  (Seems not likely to be the case with you unless **2.** of this list is also true).
5. The browser isn't rendering it properly because there no content in `.ui-content`.  (Again, not likely, but you could try adding some `Lorem Ipsum` and see if that fixes it).

If it is none of the above, then either you have touched on some obscure bug in jquery.mobile, or, there is some other highly specific issue that you somehow managed to expose.  In either case, you can add custom css that should fix it (perhaps using this inside a media query would be wise):

One of the following will work:

```
.ui-navbar ul {
               white-space:pre-wrap;
              }
// The above introduces a margin that may not be acceptable
.ui-navbar .ui-btn-inner, .ui-navbar .ui-btn-text {
               font-size:12px /* or something else that works */ !important;
 }
// The above may look too small
.ui-navbar li {
                max-width:33%;
               }
```

All of the above may introduce problems on various devices, so it is advisable to debug your code and find out what is causing this.  Keep in mind that the newest jquery.mobile version claims to have fixed all visual navbar related bugs so **this shouldn't be happening**.  With that as a context for looking, remember that the number of subtle errors that can trigger unexpected visual flaws are numerous.  This is perhaps more true for jquery.mobile than most other frameworks, because javascript is so heavily used for page styling.  However, it is not likely to be something that will require a lot of work, and or code re-writing / hacking.  Once you get to it, it should be obvious and simple.

Comment: I added the jQM theme using VisualStudio's NuGet so the jQM version is the one tested with the theme that I'm using.
The only custom css that I have is used to style a particular button so I don't think it may be related to this problem.
I've looked for malformed tags and I've found that I had 2 `<head>` tags but removing one have not changed the result.
The `<head>` is copied from the theme sample so I assume that every file is linked in the right order.
Actually there's a contest, I've just deleted it from the screens.
Your first CSS rule makes the text disappear, the others won't fix it :(

Comment: Are there any apps for windows phone, or any way at all, to see the computed style that is rendering there?  That would at least tell you what css rule is causing the issue.  Also, I didn't realize you were using the jQM Metro theme.  It shouldn't matter, but there may be some adjustments therein that render my answer inaccurate.  It does however, seem odd that any adjustments therein would cause the css to render improperly on the intended target platform.

Comment: You could also try - just for kicks - taking my last CSS rule, and changing it to 30%.  Worth a shot.